# True constraint in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints

I have a table which contains the columns "Grade" and "Finished Course". I have a foreign key constraint which limits the value of Grade from A-F. The question i have is: How do i make it so that the "Grade" column can only contain A-E if the Finished Course is true? otherwise it can only have the value F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add check constraint for this, like:

```
alter table Table1 add constraint CK_Grade
check (
        (FinishedCourse = 0 and Grade = 'F') or
        (FinishedCourse = 1 and Grade <> 'F')
        -- you can use in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), but since you have foreign key,
        -- it's enough to check Grade <> 'F'
)
```

or

```
alter table Table1 add constraint CK_Grade
check (FinishedCourse = case when Grade = 'F' then 0 else 1 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add Finished Course column to your 'foreign' "Grade_Lookup" (my name) table and use a composite foreign key constraint? e.g.

`...
FOREIGN KEY (Grade, Finished_Course) REFERENCES Grade_Lookup (Grade, Finished_Course)
...`

You'd need to add an extra record in `Grade_Lookup` to handle Grade = F, Finished_Course = True.